# "viewig" typo in Documentation help

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, typographical-error

Trivial, but on the [Documentation Votes help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-voting), at the very bottom:

> Dismiss an improvement request by ***viewig*** a topic, and clicking dismiss in the expanded improvement request pane.

Just an FYI for whoever can update that :)

Also, I noticed the line above it puts quotes around "dismiss", so while you're at it, maybe make that consistent?

(see, some people do read the help pages!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.